# Resize the details window in the software updater

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, update-manager

**EDIT 2018-01-23:**

I know that my question is closed and that I am one of the voters to close it, but I recently did a clean install of Xubuntu on my system with no other DEs installed and with the NVIDIA 390 drivers installed.  Well, this is not an issue now and is working properly.  Just thought that I would pass that on.  Thank you!

---

This is really more of a cosmetic question, and it not causing me any problems really.  It is more of an annoyance though.

The problem I have is that when I use the GUI software update, the details window where it shows the progress of the applications that are being downloaded is very narrow and I can't see how to resize it.

[image]

I can't see anything in the `dconf-manager` that might control the details window either.

[image]

The next details window after that where it shows the progress of the installing is fine.

Any ideas on where I can look to get the window to resize or fit to?

Comment: Isn't it a bug?

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't know.  Maybe I should look.  =)

Comment: Here you go: [Bug #1690541](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1690541) and [Bug #1689668](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/1689668). I've also seen it, and oddly enough, only on machines with Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: @mikewhatever Good find.  I kept finding the wrong ones.  Indeed, I have an NVIDIA GPU.  Good to know.