# Can't seem to install anything by snap

Tags: software-installation, snap

I had tried to install application through snap on Ubuntu  18.04.01 LTS (OS Type: 64 bit).

when i tried to install notepad-plus-plus i got the following errors.

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
Setup snap "notepad-plus-plus" (167) security profiles (cannot setup udev for snap "notepad-plus-plus": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Setup snap "notepad-plus-plus" (167) security profiles (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect notepad-plus-plus:opengl to core:opengl (cannot setup udev for snap "notepad-plus-plus": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect notepad-plus-plus:opengl to core:opengl (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
```

On gimp (2.10) installation I got the following errors. looks awfully similar to previous one

```
sudo snap install gimp
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "gimp" (70) security profiles (cannot setup udev for snap "gimp": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Setup snap "gimp" (70) security profiles (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect gimp:opengl to core:opengl (cannot setup udev for snap "gimp": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect gimp:opengl to core:opengl (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
```

I didn't have any clue how to solve them. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Looks like `odev` itself is having issues.  Try reinstalling `udev`.  `sudo apt install --reinstall udev`

Comment: @Terrance still after reinstalling udev got the same error

Comment: I suspect the main problem is "cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2". So i searched the net on it and got load of other same snap problems (most with people "installing snaps within LXD container"). 

Anyway one solution given by stgraber at github.com was "udevd isn't running inside a privileged container, but that shouldn't really be a problem, and it clearly isn't since running the thing again then makes it work." 

I know container had nothing to do with snap but maybe it might just give a clue what wrong @Terrance .

Comment: I don't use containers, and that actually might be your problem there.  Unfortunately, I cannot duplicate your problem so I would be no help from here on.  Please edit your question and add that you are running this in a LXD container so that hopefully someone that is running a container might know what to do.  I wish I was more help.

Comment: @Terrance No I am not running this in LXD container. it just an example of other peoples having the same problem whom are running sanp in LXD container.

Comment: @Terrance Sir can I give you teamviewer ID, pass so u can have a closer look

Comment: I don't have teamviewer, nor will I use it.  But that is OK.  From what I am finding is that it is a bug with the snapd.  You might need to completely remove the snap part and reinstall it.  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868959  That bug there shows a version that it should be to.  Since you are running 18.04.1 you might be at the newest version available.  However, you may also need to reinstall the OS.  I had a bug before in graphics that was fixed by a reinstall.  Just showing https://askubuntu.com/q/947884/231142 .  One other thing you can try run it without sudo

Comment: @Terrance Can't reinstall OS because it a production server; plus I have no guarantee this will solve the problem (I had installed the OS just a week ago, so even if I will reinstall the OS; I will go through all the steps as before and will for surely be standing again here where I am standing now. So all in all not a viable solution for me.)
As far as install without sudo is concerned, when anybody install through snap (even if they had not used sudo in front; they will be asked for admin password and from there on it the same sad story as before.

Answer (score 2):

I came looking for answers because I experienced the same issue. However, following the recommendation by @Terrance to install without sudo fixed the problem. The installation was successful without the usual errors. One more thing happened though. Launching the application from the software center ( or application center ) wasn't successful as the application just didn't start so I resorted to the commandline which gave the following result:

```
:~$ notepad-plus-plus
You need to connect this snap to the wine-platform snap.

snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug
snap install wine-platform
snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable

Remove deprecated wine-platform-i386 snap.

snap remove wine-platform-i386
```

After these steps were carried out, notepad is now running.

Note: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: even when I tried to install without sudo gave me the same error (except   before it error number was 167 and now it is 173 i.e.    error: cannot perform the following tasks:
    - Setup snap "notepad-plus-plus" (173) security profiles (cannot setup udev for snap "notepad-plus-plus": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
    udev output:
    )